# Batch file to list files and folders with parent directories

Tags: file, batch-file, directory, parent

I have seen scripts from different people who have suggested the code denoted down below:

```
    @echo off
    setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
    pushd %1
    set "tab=   "
    set "indent="
    call :listFolder >report.txt
    exit /b

    :listFolder
    setlocal
    set "indent=%indent%%tab%"

    for /d %%F in (*) do (
      echo %indent%%%F
      pushd "%%F"
      call :listFolder
      popd
    )
    for %%F in (*) do echo %indent%%%F

exit /b
```

which outputs:

```
Folder 1
   Subfolder 1
      Filename 1
   Subfolder 2
      Filename 1
Folder 2
   Subfolder 1
      Filename 2
      Filename 2
```

This worked great for a while but I was wondering is there way to do the same idea but have the parent folder separated by a tab.

```
Folder 1
Folder 1    Subfolder 1
Folder 1    Subfolder 1     Filename 1
Folder 1    Subfolder 2
Folder 1    Subfolder 2     Filename 1
Folder 2
Folder 2    Subfolder 1
Folder 2    Subfolder 1     Filename 2
Folder 2    Subfolder 1     Filename 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@echo OFF
SETLOCAL
pushd %1
set "tab=/"
SET "currdir=%cd%"
call :listFolder >report.txt
popd
GOTO :eof

:listFolder
setlocal
for /d %%a in (*) do (
 SET "name=%%~fa"
 SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
 SET name=!name:%currdir%=!
 SET name=!name:\=%tab%!
 ECHO !name!
 ENDLOCAL
 pushd "%%a"
 call :listFolder
 popd
)
for %%a in (*) do (
 SET "name=%%~fa"
 SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
 SET name=!name:%currdir%=!
 SET name=!name:\=%tab%!
 ECHO !name!
 ENDLOCAL
)

GOTO :eof
```

Interesting exercise.

Essentially, the report then becomes "do a `dir/s/b` list, but replace the `\` with <kbd>Tab</kbd> and omit the current directory" - but that simple scheme doesn't produce the same sequence...

( I also replaced tab with `/` to make it easier to see, tabs not being particularly obvious and all ) - just a matter of choosing a character that suits...

Comment: this works really great! thanks so much. I'm wondering why is the GOTO :eof necessary? I'm still pretty much a novice when it comes to scripting but what would be the purpose of that line.

Comment: I wanted it that way instead of a dir /s/b cause now I can put into excel and fitler table. Makes it easy to sort files or find pictures in a folder that I forgot haha. But yea thanks a lot! =)

Comment: I use `goto :eof` to close a local environment and return. I suppose `exit /b` does the same thing. Tomato/tomato.

Answer (score 0):

Another version:

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set "pwd=%~1"
if "%pwd%"=="" set "pwd=%cd%"

pushd "%pwd%"
set "indent=   "
call :listFolder1 "%pwd%"
exit /b

:listFolder1 %1
setlocal
set curdir=%~1
for /d %%F in (*) do (
    echo %curdir%%indent%%%F
    for %%S in (*) do echo %curdir%%indent%%%F%indent%%%S
    pushd %%F
    call :listFolder1 "%curdir%%indent%%%F"
    popd
)
```